# Unity Google Cardboard reverts any camera changes made when built on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I am working with Google Cardboard through Unity on a virtual reality project in which the view slowly changes from stereoscopic VR (a slightly different image in each eye) to monoscopic VR (the same image in each eye).

I can edit the cameras in the Unity Editor, and the changes work as intended in the Game window within the Editor, but when I build the project onto an Android phone, all the user can see is the scene through the default Google Cardboard camera setup.

This seems to happen as long as "Virtual Reality Supported" checkbox in the Player Settings menu is flagged. Does anyone know why this happens and if it can be overcome?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because user's well being is our most precious resource in VR, so the devs of the SDK (GVR and OVR alike) have made some decisions to make messing with the camera intentionally convoluted - to avoid people sayich that the tech is at fault when all their audience feels sick because they changed the FOV or something.
I believe you can still do what you want to do by scaling the camera parent